# Jmeter -- Exception faced while recording

Tags: exception, proxy, jmeter

1. Trying to record through a PC located in UK and we are RDP from India
2. JMeter version used is 2.13r1665067
3. Proxy setting used and done in Mozilla Firefox as below :

In manual proxy configuration : Http proxy : localhost Port : 8080

4. Started Jmeter from command prompt using below

jmeter.bat -H 195.59.125.25 -P 57378

5. From Jmeter GUI we added the below :
   a. Thread group 
   -- recording controller
   -- Http Request defaults
   -- View results tree
   b. Workbench
   -- HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
   under Recorder we have provided below details :
   Port : 8080 
   Target Controller : Test plan> Thread group > Recording controller
6. We clicked on Start and go to FF browser and type any URL we recieve below error message.
7. org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://195.59.125.25:57378 refused
8. With a big message continued

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message you get, JMeter is not able to connect to your proxy:

> -H 195.59.125.25 -P 57378

So you will have to check connectivity and potentially open firewall to be able to record

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of recording a JMeter script is using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which doesn't require any extra configuration, it will pick up Chrome proxy settings, it will automatically add headers, think times, etc.

However if you're going to execute script using your particularly that machine (via proxy) make sure that:

- proxy server is up-and-running and it accepts connections on the port 57378
- [Java has full access to network](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)
- you proxy server won't be a bottleneck